# Table Cell width issue in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html-table

The following code is supposed to make the right 60% of the display red. It does in Chrome, but does not in Firefox. In Firefox, it makes the whole screen red. Can anybody help me fix this?

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td id="l" width="30%" height="200px"></td>
    <td id="m" width="3%"  style="background-color:green"></td>
    <td id="r" width="60%" height="200px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>    
<script>
        w = $('#r').width();
        h = $(window).height();

        $("#r").css({'width' : w, 'height' : h, 'position': 'relative', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px'});
        $("#r").append("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color:red;'></div>");

</script>
```

ps: I cannot use 'background-color:red' in 'td'; I need to append the new 'div' to the table cell as you can in the code (since this is a part of a bigger design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td id="l" width="30%" height="200px">

            </td>
            <td id="m" width="3%" style="background-color: green;">

            </td>
            <td id="r" width="60%" height="200px" style="vertical-align:top;">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>

        w = $('#r').width();
        h = $(window).height();

        $("#r").css({ 'width': w, 'height': h, 'position': 'relative' });
        $("#r").append("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; background-color:red;'></div>");

    </script>
```

Comment: I just realized that this solution just transfers the red rectangle. The width of the red area is not screenwidth*60% (that is what we need); instead, the width is screenwidth. You need to scroll to the right to see the whole rectangle. This problem is still with Firefox. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: $("#r").append("<div style='width: 100%; height: "+h+"px; position: absolute; background-color:red;'></div>");

Comment: what is the version of your firefox. i tried , it worked and then i wrote here.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the position from absolute to relative worked for me in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td id="l" width="30%" height="200px"></td>
    <td id="m" width="3%"  style="background-color:green"></td>
    <td id="r" width="60%" height="200px"></td>
    </tr>

</table>    
<script>
        w = $('#r').width();
        h = $(window).height();

        $("#r").css({'width' : w, 'height' : h, 'position': 'relative', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px'});
        $("#r").append("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color:red;'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

TD's don't work well with position relative so the DIV is getting it's position from main parent.

Perhaps this will work better for you just wrapping the contents of the cell in a DIV

```
  $("#r").wrapInner("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:red;'></div>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DCCU9/